# Best practice when setting boolean values in PreparedStarement

Tags: java, mysql

So I have a MYSQL db in which boolean values are stored as `binary(1)`. I was to investigate why certain queries were slow even though there was an index on the relevant columns. The issue was that when building the SELECT query, the system was using the `setBoolean` method of `PreparedStatement` which, as I understand it, converts the value to MYSQL `TINYINT`. The query found the correct rows, but never used the index since the index was on a binary column. However, if I instead used the `setString` method and converted the boolean to a string, namely `'0'` for `false` and `'1'` for `true`, MYSQL was able to use the index and find the wanted rows fast.

Basically, the first query is what I got when using `setBoolean` and the second when using `setString`:

```
SELECT someColumn FROM table WHERE binaryColumn = 1 //Does not use index
SELECT someColumn FROM table WHERE binaryColumn = '1'//Uses index
```

In Java the change was this:

```
PreparedStatement ps1 = ...
ps1.setBoolean(1, true);
...

PreparedStatement ps2 = ...
ps2.setString(1, "1");
...
```

My question is simply if there is a **better** way to do this? Everything works fine but for some reason I think the code "smells" but I cant really motivate why.

Comment: I think `binary(n)` data type is mapped to `byte[]` in java/JDBC. When string is used driver is able to implicitly convert that to byte[] and use index. It is unable to do so when a boolean is passed.

Comment: `binary` is the wrong type to use for a boolean column.  The purpose of a `binary` column is to store binary data, things like a small image, maybe an encryption key -- you know, small blocks of bytes.  You probably wanted a `TINYINT` or a `boolean` column (same thing)

Comment: I didn't design the db so this is what I have to work with. @IanMcLaird

Comment: That's fine, I just meant that the reason you think the code "smells" is because of an underlying database design wart.  If you can't change the database design, then you're really more or less stuck with the solution you have, or something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer always the setBoolean, because of abstraction.

The real interesting point is when your DB uses the index.

The optimizier of the DB use a index only, if it makes sense. If you have 1000 entries and a booleanvalue only split it into 50/50 it make no sense for that index, especial when its not the PK - but if you use a additional limitation, to get only 10 rows, as result, a good optimizer should use the index you specified - maybe a "composed index" on 2 columns (booleanColumn1, StringColumn1)

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. In the particular table the distribution is more 99.9% to 0.01% so the index really helped alot, once it was used.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses TINYINT(1) for the SQL BOOL/BOOLEAN. So I would change the data type to BOOLEAN, in accordance to standard SQL.

By your relay, the issue should then be resolved. By the way BIT(1) would be another option.